# MATLAB memory pileup in batch printing of figures

Tags: matlab, batch-file, memory-leaks

I am printing a large number of figures to files. After a certain number, I get an out of memory error which a lot of other people have reported as well.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032117/why-does-matlab-slow-down-when-printing-lots-of-png-figures) addresses the problem, but I cannot use the solution as I am printing various kinds of graphs including surface, plot, contour, quiver and scatter.

Is there a practical solution or a feasible workaround for this memory pileup problem that would allow to run the entire image printing in an unsupervised batch?

Comment: Is moving to 64bit Matlab possible/feasible?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem in 32 and 64 bit both

Comment: Why can you not use the solution proposed in the question you linked? You can do `figure(1); surf(...); figure(2); plot(...); figure(3); scatter(...)` to create figures with a known handle. Inside the loop, you then do `figure(1); update_surf(...); figure(2); update_plot(...); figure(3); update_scatter(...);`, so that you always access the original figures.

Comment: If the solution by @Shoelzer works, go for it. When you run into memory release problems in general, you may want to look into the `pack` function.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin pack wasn't working in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a memory leak. You may be able to help Matlab release the leaked memory by [closing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/close.html) each figure after printing. Create a new figure for each thing you want to print.

```
% item 1
f = figure;
% plot
% print
close(f)

% item 2
f = figure;
% plot
% print
close(f)
```

Comment: Working like a charm :)

Comment: I wonder if this is related to [this bug with `hardcopy`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/41367-hardcopy-slower-with-more-figures-open)? I believe that the `print` function uses `hardcopy` under the hood in `private/render`.